# Why is local notification fired before its fire date?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have logged the local notification.

{fire date = Friday, April 18, 2014 at 9:00:00 PM India Standard Time, time zone = Asia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800, repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Friday, April 18, 2014 at 9:00:00 PM India Standard Time, user info = {
    Key =     (
        "18/04/2014",
        "11:18:07",
        Tab,
        "Telma H",
        "80 mg",
        "1OD (Once a day)",
        "for 5 days",
        5
    );
}}

One can see that fire date is in "PM" but it is firing right away. I have scheduled it as below.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    [df setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

    NSDate *dateToday = [NSDate date];

    NSString *time = @"09:00 PM";

    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd "];
    NSString *todayString = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSString *todaysTime = [todayString stringByAppendingString:time];

    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:todaysTime];

    NSTimeInterval ti = [date timeIntervalSinceDate:dateToday];
    [localNotification setFireDate:[dateToday dateByAddingTimeInterval:ti]];
    [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    [localNotification setAlertBody:@"Local Notification" ];
    [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Open App"];
    [localNotification setHasAction:YES];
    [localNotification setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: Perhaps another notification has been scheduled before? Try calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]` before scheduling the new notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
```

This shows that time zone's is default which does not point to your time zone.

Comment: I don't know what happens. But my problem is solve without change of any code. Seems strange!!

Comment: clean and then build and run is best practice .

Comment: Nope. I have even tried deletion from SIMULATOR before.